# Openfire to use MySQL ENCRYPT

Tags: mysql, encryption, openfire, credentials

I have Openfire up and running with default settings. Also there is some user database where users are already stored with MySQL ENCRYPT method (Linux crypt()).

Is it possible to allow Openfire to understand those credentials?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible with custom SQL request. Change provider.auth.className to org.jivesoftware.openfire.auth.JDBCAuthProvider
Then create requests depending on your current database